# Getting all files that contains a word in a specific word set in a terminal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, grep

What I am trying to achieve is, I want to find all files under my current root directory that contains words that are in a `.txt` file. In more details, I want to find all files that uses a bootstrap3 classname (any file extension).

So, basically, I will have a `.txt` that has a list of all bootstrap3 class names (e.g. `col-md-1`, `container-fluid`, etc.)

I've used `grep -lir <word>` to search the files that has the text, but what I want to do is return the files that has any of the words in a specific word set.

How would this work?

Comment: Look into the -f option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man grep`:

```
       -f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If  this  option  is
              used  multiple  times  or  is  combined with the -e (--regexp)
              option,  search  for  all  patterns  given.   The  empty  file
              contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Something like `grep -irl -f words.txt dir-to-search`